# HDMI output suddenly stopped working

Tags: fedora, gnome, nvidia, xrandr, hdmi

I installed a fresh Fedora 36 onto my MSI-GS75 laptop yesterday and everything was going smooth until about half an hour ago.

The laptop was connected to a 65' 4k TV via a HDMI port on the laptop. It was working fine for most of the day and I was testing outputting some steam games onto the TV.

Then suddenly the laptop stops detecting the TV in GNOME's display settings for no apparent reason. I ran some commands to see if it can detect the HDMI output or the TV but no success.

I've tested connecting the TV to another computer and that works fine, so the issue isn't on the TV or the HDMI cable's end. I've tried connecting another HDMI monitor to the laptop and that also wasn't detected.

I've noticed that a xrandr query shows that the HDMI port is disconnected, I have tried running `xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --auto` but to no success

I'll list the terminal outputs below, any ideas?

```
[nocnoc@nocnoc-msi-gs75 ~]$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for nocnoc: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:160 memory:ac000000-acffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:ad000000-ad07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:144 memory:ab000000-abffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff


[nocnoc@nocnoc-msi-gs75 ~]$ xrandr --query
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     74.76    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   700x525       74.76    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432       75.00  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)


[nocnoc@nocnoc-msi-gs75 ~]$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/381x1080/214+0+0  eDP-1


[nocnoc@nocnoc-msi-gs75 ~]$ sudo systemctl status display-manager
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-08-05 14:02:16 CEST; 11min ago
   Main PID: 2057 (gdm)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18948)
     Memory: 5.8M
        CPU: 215ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─ 2057 /usr/sbin/gdm

Aug 05 14:02:16 nocnoc-msi-gs75 systemd[1]: Starting gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager...
Aug 05 14:02:16 nocnoc-msi-gs75 systemd[1]: Started gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.
Aug 05 14:02:22 nocnoc-msi-gs75 gdm-password][2565]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Aug 05 14:02:22 nocnoc-msi-gs75 gdm-password][2565]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Aug 05 14:02:28 nocnoc-msi-gs75 gdm[2057]: Gdm: Child process -2114 was already dead.
```

Comment: Whenever that happens to me, all I can do is reboot which always fixes it. Sometimes when a display isn't connected and switched on, it's simply not detected. 

Comment: @DanMan Yes, the problem seemed to fix itself, not after one reboot, but many. The fact that everything works now without any explanation is unsettling to me. In case it breaks again at an important time

Comment: Certainly is annoying, but it's probably up to Nvidia to fix that since their driver isn't FOSS.

Comment: I'm having this issue too all of a sudden. Can't find the solution anywhere. Have tried rebooting / power cycling several times. Booting into a different (Ubuntu) install fixes the issue, so it definitely seems like an OS issue, but why did it happen and how can I fix it?